# Russian prefix in caption

Tags: graphics, pdftex, captions, cyrillic, russian

I'm trying to add an image in `pdfLaTeX` like so:

```latex
\documentclass{paper}

% Russian language
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

% Links
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}

% Images
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{
  {images/}
}

\begin{document}
  Небольшое вступление

  \begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{dw-scheduler.png}
    \caption{Какой-то текст}
  \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

For some reason, the caption is being prefixed with English `Fig. 1:` instead of `Рис. 1:`
[image]

This also has no effect whatsoever:

```latex
\addto\captionsrussian{\renewcommand{\figurename}{Рис.}}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Do you have a reason for using the `paper` document class? The reason I ask is that the issue you've encountered does *not* arise when one uses a different document class, say, `article` or `report`.

Comment: @Mico, actually, no particular reason except that `paper` looks better than `article`. (I would like to keep using `paper`.)

Comment: The `paper` document class was last updated in 1996. A lot of the code in `paper.cls` is cruft. Unless you can find someone who's able and willing to fix this cruft, you may be better off using a document class that continues to be maintained.

Comment: @Mico, I see, thanks for figuring this out. The problem is indeed in the `paper` document class. Guess I have to find something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The class uses \figureshortname:

```
\documentclass{paper}

% Russian language
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\renewcommand\figureshortname{Рис.}
% Links
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}

% Images
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{
  {images/}
}

\begin{document}
  Небольшое вступление

  \begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    %\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{dw-scheduler.png}
    \caption{Какой-то текст}
  \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd prefer the “official” interface `\addto\captionsrussian{\renewcommand{\figureshortname}{Рис.}}`